# Self-Solving Chess Problems

Tags: problems

Are there any longer "problems" like [this](http://www.apronus.com/chess/chess-board.html?d=_________________P__P____p________________p_P____P_Pp____K_k_____&w=8&h=8), which is white to move and mate in 6?

(Namely, where one is actually forced to achieve the "goal".)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Yes, there are problems longer than 6 moves, but not many in a practical sense.

Comment: It's not quite the same thing, but you might be interested in "selfmates", in which your job (as White) is to force Black to checkmate you.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: The one I gave isn't practical either, unless one thinks of it as practicing calculating out the pawn race.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Wikipedia page on Joke chess problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke_chess_problem) has a section on self-solving chess problems, and it links to [Tim Krabbé's Open Chess Diary](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary_14.htm), where a few more examples are in item 267. He calls them "no-brainers".